# Applying the cauchy criterion when the series are not convergent(divergent)

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences, divergent-series

$$b_n=\frac{x}{1}+\frac{x+1}{3}+\frac{x+2}{5}+...+\frac{x+n}{2n+1},x\gt1$$
$$c_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt1}+\frac{1}{\sqrt2}+...+\frac{1}{\sqrt n},n\geq1$$
I'm having troubles with the cauchy criterion and I do not understand how to apply it when the series are not convergent. These exercises are telling me to use the cauchy criterion $$\lvert b_{n+p}-b_{n}\rvert<ε$$.

Is the absolute value inside always positive? I've learned in school that for every negative value inside the absolute value symbol it changes to a positive value.
Ex: $\lvert-9\rvert$=$9$ or $\lvert -2x-5 \rvert$=$2x+5$.

However since these series are not convergent I need to prove that by using the criterion with epsilon.How do you apply that? If you apply the criterion can you reduce terms if they are inside the absolute value symbol?

Comment: No one? I really need help!

Comment: What's the exact question here? Are you trying to show that $b_n$ diverges? Or that $c_n$ diverges? Or something else?

Comment: @rwbogl The question is:,, How do you use the cauchy criterion for these series if they are not convergent?''I asked if you use that formula with n+p terms.If you use it that means you reduce some terms inside the absolute value symbol |b(n+p)-b(n)|?

Comment: Can't claim $|-2x-5|=2x+5$ without some info about $x.$

Comment: Well if you're trying to show that the sequence *diverges*, then you would show that, for $\epsilon$, you can choose arbitrarily large $n$ such that $|a_{n + p} - a_n| \geq \epsilon$. That's the Cauchy criterion. But there are probably easier ways to show that $b_n$ diverges.

Comment: @rwbogl That's what the exercise specified. It wants to show a proof by using the cauchy criterion.

Comment: @coffeemath So if you have a negative value inside the absolute value symbol that means the value remains the same or it changes to a positive value?

Comment: wolly-- one needs the sign of $2x+5$ to simplify that absolute value. Would arrive at $2x+5$ if positive, otherwise $-2x-5.$ But for some $x$ sign of $2x+5$ is negative, some positive.